# AWS SSO using SAML in php application

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, saml, simplesamlphp

I used following Reference URL to configure the AWS SSO for our application. But I'm getting following error from AWS "Your request included an invalid SAML response. To logout, click here",

https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install
https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp

http://www.ipragmatech.com/aws-sso-saml2-simplesamlphp/
https://vlasenko.org/2015/04/05/howto-register-aws-saml-metadata-in-simplesamlphp/

But I dont know what i missing in simplesamlphp configuration

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon AWS troubleshooting guide suggests checking that the SAML response has a attribute with name https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role with a attribute value of the ARN of a role or ARN of the SAML provider.

You can use [this chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saml-devtools-extension/jndllhgbinhiiddokbeoeepbppdnhhio?utm_source=gmail) to view the content of your SAML response

See the [guide for more info](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_saml.html)

Comment: Yes, SAML response coming with "Name" attribute, But how can i avoid "Name" attribute in config file. 10 => array(
               'class' => 'core:AttributeAdd',
               'https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role' =>
                array('arn:aws:iam::arn:aws:iam::<accountno>:role/<rolename>,arn:aws:iam::<accountno>:saml-provider/<provider-name>')
           ),
           20 => array(
              'class' => 'core:AttributeCopy',
              'uid' => 'https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/RoleSessionName',
           ),

Comment: Why would you want to avoid it?